# PROBLEMA - ¿Por qué salen todos los resultados iguales?

Tags: r, funciones, rstudio, while

Estoy intentando calcular el número de agentes que debe tener un call center pero los resultados apenas cambian entre sí, son prácticamente iguales como se muestra a continuación:

[image: Resultado función resource]

Este número de agentes se calcula en la función ***resource***, la cuál devolverá una columna con los resultados. El número de agentes irá incrementándose hasta que se alcance el nivel de servicio deseado (***gos_target***). Entonces, si **gos<gostarget**, el número de agentes se incrementará en 1 y habrá que calcular un nuevo valor de *gos*. Para poder calcular el nuevo valor de *gos* *service_level*, necesito calcular la función *erlang_c*.

Llamamos a la función *resource* de la siguiente manera: resource(rate = i, duration= 103, target= 20, gos_target=85/100, interval = 3600); donde todos los datos menos ***rate*** son fijos. *Rate* es el número de llamadas recibidas, es decir, en mis datos tengo una columna donde en cada fila viene un número de llamadas recibidas en función de la hora, día... y lo que se pretende es que la función vaya fila por fila obteniendo el número de agentes de acuerdo a la cantidad de llamadas.

Ejemplo inventado: imagina que la tercera fila tiene un valor de = 200. Significa que se recibieron 200 llamadas en esa hora, por tanto, con ese numero se calculará la *intensity* = 10 , luego el *erlang_c* = 0.6821, service_level = 0.390 y por ultimo *resource* = 14 = nº agentes. (Estos resultados no se han calculado con los mismos valores de entrada que los míos).

El problema está en que al compilar me salen valores muy parecidos entre sí, lo que no tiene sentido. No debería salir lo mismo si recibes 7 llamadas la hora a si recibes 50.

A continuación, os dejo el código:

```
ds <- dataset

library(dplyr)

intensity <- function(rate, duration, interval) { 
  return (rate / interval) * duration
}

erlang_c <- function(agents, rate, duration, interval) {
  int <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
  erlang_b_inv <- 1
  for (i in 1:agents) {
    erlang_b_inv <- 1 + erlang_b_inv * i / int
  }
  erlang_b <- 1 / erlang_b_inv
  return (agents * erlang_b / (agents - int * (1 - erlang_b)))
}


service_level <- function(agents, rate, duration, target, interval) {
  pw <- erlang_c(agents, rate, duration, interval)
  int <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
  #a <- (pw * exp(-(agents - int)))
  #b <- (target / duration)
  a <- exp(-(agents-int)*(target/duration))
  return (1 - (pw*(a)))
}

resource <- function(rate, duration, target, gos_target, interval) {
  inten <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
  agents <- ceiling(inten + 1)
  gos <- service_level(agents, rate, duration, target, interval)

  while (gos < gos_target) {
    agents <- agents + 1
    gos <- service_level(agents, rate, duration, target, interval)
  }
  return(c(agents,gos))
}


agentes_vec <- c()
gos_vec <- c()

for (i in ds$llamadas) {
  #print(i)
  res <-resource(rate = i, duration= 103, target= 20, gos_target=85/100, interval = 3600)
  agentes_vec <- c(agentes_vec, res[1])
  gos_vec <- c(gos_vec, res[2])
}


ds$agentes <- agentes_vec
ds$gos <- gos_vec
```

No consigo ver qué es lo que puede estar pasando. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias!!!
Saludos.

Comment: ¡Hola @bibitarifa! Lo que haría es comprobar a mano para un caso particular, que se cumple el resultado esperado. Tal y como das la explicación es complicado poder saber qué puede fallar ya que desconocemos el origen de la fórmula y su aplicación

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! El código funciona para un caso particular, pero no funcionaba al tener que leer una columna entera de datos y sacar los resultados en función de la fila. Creo que el problema está en cómo estoy definiendo el bucle, las salidas o entradas. Las funciones vienen de las fórmulas de Erlang y ya comprobé que funcionaban bien en un caso particular.

Comment: El bucle está correctamente definido, tiene que tratarse de un problema en el cálculo de la fórmula que te da el resultado.

Comment: Gracias @R18! Me quedo tranquila sabiendo que el bucle está bien definido. Comprobaré las funciones anteriores. Un saludo!